# can i use log4j in a jsp file? How do I initialise the logger in jsp?

Tags: jsp, log4j

I want to use the log4j logging framework in a jsp file.

The typical initialisation of log4j in a java file is:

Logger log = Logger.getLogger(loggedin.class);

How do I initialise the logger in a jsp file? Can this be done?

Comment: Read this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594931/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-log4j-within-jsp-pages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could say `<%Logger LOG= Logger.getLogger(getclass());%>` this will create a logger for the created jsp class.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking logging from JSP is not advisable. But if you really want to do it, try this,

Logger log = Logger.getLogger("loggedin.jsp");

Assuming the JSP file name is loggedin.jsp, but you can give any meaningful name to distinguish the log details.